# Getting error on DNN site

Tags: dotnetnuke

I am new to DNN. Everytime after login I am getting the following error:-

```
An error has occurred. DotNetNuke.Services.Exceptions.ModuleLoadException: The underlying system threw an exception. 
---> DotNetNuke.Services.FileSystem.FolderProviderException: The underlying system threw an exception.
---> System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object. 
at DotNetNuke.Services.FileSystem.FileManager.GetUrl(IFileInfo file) 
--- End of inner exception stack trace
--- at DotNetNuke.Services.FileSystem.FileManager.GetUrl(IFileInfo file) at DotNetNuke.UI.Skins.Controls.Logo.OnLoad(EventArgs e) 
--- End of inner exception stack trace ---
```

Can anyone tell me why this is happening. Am I doing some wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you have a problem with the LOGO you have defined in your DNN site.

Try going to the Admin/Site Settings page and uploading a new LOGO file.